# Integrating Ampère's force law to find the force between wires

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I want to find the force between parallel current carrying wires using Ampère's force law.

Ampère's force law is given as 
\begin{align}
dF&= \frac{\mu}{4\pi} \frac{I_1dL_2\times(I_2dL_2\times r_{21})}{r^2}
\\\int \mathrm{d}F&=\frac{\mu}{4\pi} \int{}{}\frac{I_1dL_1\times(I_2dL_2\times r_{21}}{r^2}
\\&=\frac{\mu}{4\pi} \int{}{}\frac{I_1dL_1\times(I_2dL_2r_{21}\sin(90))}{r^2}
\\&=\frac{\mu}{4\pi} \int{}{}\frac{I_1dL_1I_2dL_2r_{21}\sin(90)}{r^2}
\\&=\frac{\mu}{4\pi} \int{}{}\frac{I_1dL_1I_2dL_2}{r}
\\&=\frac{\mu}{4\pi} \int_{A}^{B} \int_{C}^{D}(\frac{I_1I_2}{r}dL_1)dL_2
\\&=\frac{\mu}{4\pi} \int_{A}^{B} [\frac{I_1I_2}{r}L_1]_{C}^{D}dL_2
\\&=\frac{\mu}{4\pi} \int_{A}^{B} (\frac{I_1I_2}{r}(C-D))dL_2
\\&=\frac{\mu}{4\pi} (\frac{I_1I_2}{r}(C-D)(B-A))
\end{align}

Since the length of the wire I'm calculating, is the same B-A=C-D 
$$F=\frac{\mu}{4\pi} (\frac{I_1I_2}{r}(B-A)^2)$$

How ever when I calculate the force between two wires I get
$$F=I_2 \Delta L B$$
$$F=I_2 \Delta L \frac{\mu I_1}{2 \pi r} $$
As you can see I get a slightly different answer. I really don't know where I am going wrong with this and I don't have anyone around me who I can ask this about. I would appreciate any help.Thank you.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake was assuming that the angle between $dL_2$ and $r_{12}$ is 90°=constant everywhere.

Pick one Point $r$ in vicinity of wire 2. Biot-Savat-law:

$B = \int_A^B \frac{I_2dL_2 \times e_{12}}{r_{12}^2}$ where $e_{12}$ is unit Vector pointing from some Point on the wire to the reference Point $r$. Not only the current element $I_2dL_2$ (which indeed has relative angle 90°) will make the magnetic field at the Point $r$. Also the current Elements more far apart (relative angle $\alpha$ as a function of $L_2-r$) will contribute. Thus:

$B(r) = \int_A^B \frac{I_2 sin(\alpha(L_2-r))}{|L_2-r|^2} dL_2 e_*$ .

The unit Vector $e_*$ Points perpendicular to the plane in which the reference Point and the wire lies in. Parallelity of wires 1 and 2 imply that the angle between $I_1dL_1$ and $e_*$ are 90°. The cross product with $I_1 dL_1$ and $B(r)$ can be simplified; hence:

$F= \int_C^D \frac{\mu}{4 \pi} I_1|B(L_1)|dL_1$.

Now you can switch to new variables $\delta L = L_2-L_1$, $L = L_1$ in this integral. You can perform then Integration over $L$ easy. Finally

$F = \frac{\mu I_1 I_2 \Delta L}{4 \pi} \int \frac{sin(\alpha(\delta L))}{\delta L^2}d \delta L$

where $\int \frac{sin(\alpha(\delta L))}{\delta L^2}d\delta L$ is a number.

Comment: Please don't answer "do my homework for me" type questions. This isn't a homework help site and answering them only encourages more of these types of questions that we don't want.

Comment: Ok, I will do it.